# How do i define a like RouterLink ='job/postjob' where "job" will be my lazy loading route in app.routing.ts?

Tags: angular-routing

A[enter image description here][1]nd I want to implement "postjob" as chilldren under my jobModule. so when i click a button(say postjob) and go to the link job/postjob.

routerLink in html:

```
   <li class="left">
            <a [routerLink]="['job/']">
              <i class="ti-pencil-alt"></i> Post A Job</a></li>
```

app.routing.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{path: '', redirectTo:'/index', pathMatch:'full'},
{path: 'index', component: HomepageComponent},
{path: 'contactus', component: ContactusComponent},
{path: 'aboutus', component: AboutusComponent},
{path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
{path: 'job', loadChildren: './jobs/job.module#JobModule'}
```

];

job.routing.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{path: '',
children: [
    {path: 'jobindex', component: JobsComponent},
    {path: 'postjob', component: JobpostComponent},
]
},
```

];

i want to go to job then postjob when i click to "Post a job".

Comment: why dont you use  job/postjob in the routerLink ? or add   { path: '', redirectTo: 'postjob'', pathMatch: 'full' },   in your jobModule router

Comment: redirectTo: can't be added when we have children route.

Comment: Since when? Im gonna check but I'm pretty sure I use it on my project on children

Comment: I mean when I have children route under any route path. I can't use redirectTo: in that route.